# How to update with Sequelize with 'NOW()' on a timestamp?

Tags: node.js, datetime, sql-update, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
model.updateAttributes({syncedAt: 'NOW()'});
```

Obviously, that doesn't work because it just gets passed as a string. I want to avoid passing a node constructed timestamp, because later I compare it to another 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' field and the database and source could be running different times.

Is my only option to just make a database procedure and call that?

Comment: How about `new Date().toString()`

Comment: @laggingreflex I could just use moment().format(), but I wanted to avoid later comparing a database time to a client side generated time.

Comment: Why don't you enable timestamps, so updatedAt will be updated if you simply call model.update({},{where:{my_primary_key:value}})

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use `Sequelize.fn` to wrap it appropriately:

```
instance.updateAttributes({syncedAt: sequelize.fn('NOW')});
```

Here's a full working example:

```
'use strict';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(/*database*/'test', /*username*/'test', /*password*/'test',
    {host: 'localhost', dialect: 'postgres'});

var model = sequelize.define('model', {
    syncedAt: {type: Sequelize.DATE}
});

sequelize.sync({force: true})
    .then(function () {
        return model.create({});
    })
    .then(function () {
        return model.find({});
    })
    .then(function(instance){
        return instance.updateAttributes({syncedAt: sequelize.fn('NOW')});
    })
    .then(function () {
        process.exit(0);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('Caught error! ' + err);
    });
```

That produces

```
UPDATE "models" SET "syncedAt"=NOW(),"updatedAt"='2015-02-09 18:05:28.989 +00:00' WHERE "id"=1
```

Comment: Thanks! sequelize.fn('NOW') is exactly what I needed.

Comment: is sequelize.fn('NOW(6)') supported for storing fractional seconds/microseconds?  since Sequelize.DATE(6) datatype is now supported if we are using mysql >= 5.6

Comment: OK: sequelize.fn('NOW', 6) is supported for storing fractional seconds/microseconds.

Comment: Note that this sets the instance's syncedAt attribute to `{fn: "NOW", args: []}` and not the current timestamp (since this is determined by the database).

Comment: Good Job! Thanks.

Comment: To add to @mauvm's note, if you need the value _after_ setting it, remember to first call `instance.save()` to actually update the database side, and to also then call `instance.reload()` to get that new timestamp loaded in as an actual timestamp instead of as a function placeholder.

Answer (score 37):

Worth mentioning (for people coming here via search) that NOW() isn't standard and doesn't work on SQL server - so don't do this if you care about portability.

```
sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
```

may work better

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed for using SQLite3 with Sequelize.

Answer (score 3):

you can use: `sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')`.
Example:

```
await PurchaseModel.update( {purchase_date : sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') }, { where: {id: purchaseId} } );
```